# Reuse Subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to use a CTE to use a subquery in two parts of the query. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have CTEs. Is there a way to do this without creating a temporary variable?

I don't have a specific query to simplify. I want to know the general technique. If you need a concrete example, here's one with CTE:

```
with subquery as (select * from t)
select *, (select count(*) from subquery c) from subquery a, subquery b
```

What is the equivalent in MySQL?

Comment: Could you show the actual query you want to simplify?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I have read the other questions where people simplify for the particular situation without answering this part of the question. I want to reuse the query in a general sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, the closest equivalent in MySQL is by [creating a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html):

```
create view subquery as select * from t;

select *, (select count(*) from subquery c) from subquery a, subquery b;
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc92a/1).